# Copying a .jar file from my system to the disk -- is there a general solution for both .jar projects and non .jar projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

My current project has a folder with dependencies, that is, .jar files. I was wondering if it'd be possible to copy any one of those .jar files to my disk.

I'm currently developing this project as a standard Eclipse Java project, but one day I'll want to deploy this project as a .jar file, too, so the solution would have to work both for the moment, and for the future situation as well.

Thanks

Comment: is your project like a standalone application (like a calculator for example or somethiing that should run on a server? if first, how should it start (user downloads and executes installller or by simplle click on web)?

Comment: It's a compiler. It runs client-side. Think of something like javac.

Answer (score 0):

[image: How to export jar]

I Think this is what you are after: 
Eclipse has an export function that also packages used library jars into the exported jar.

File->Export->Runnable Jar file -> Package Required libraries into generated JAR

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough.I want to be able to extract the files *programatically*, independently of having my files deployed either as just a bunch of .class files or contained in a .jar file. My current issue to start with, is that while if I'm not mistaken, I have to extract the .jar file from my system to the disk in distinct ways, depending on the fact that my system was deployed either as a .jar file or not.